# Code compiled on RHEL 8 using gcc not working on RHEL 6. Getting error `GLIBC_2.14' not found

Tags: gcc, glibc, rhel, libc

We are having an application which is built using **gcc** on **RHEL 8**.
When we run the executable for this application on **RHEL 6** we are getting error `GLIBC_2.14' not found required by application.
What are the options which can make **application built on RHEL 8** using gcc run on **RHEL 6**.

Answer (score 2):

> What are the options which can make application built on RHEL 8 using gcc run on RHEL 6.

Running the application in a docker container may be a reasonable option.

You could also install GLIBC-2.14 (or newer) in parallel to the system GLIBC. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617).